# Opening multiple python files from folder

Tags: python, biopython

I am trying to take a folder which contains 9 files, each containing FASTA records of separate genes, and remove duplicate records.  I want to set it up so that the script is called with the folder that contains the genes as the first parameter, and a new folder name to rewrite the new files without duplicates to.  However, if the files are stored in a folder called results within the current directory it is not letting me open any of the gene files within that folder to process them for duplicates.  I have searched around and it seems that I should be able to call python's open() function with a string of the file name like this:

`input_handle = open(f, "r")`

This line is not allowng me to  open the file to read its contents, and I think it may have something to do with the type of f, which shows to be type 'str' when I call type(f)

Also, if I use the full path:

`input_handle = open('~/Documents/Research/Scala/hiv-biojava-scala/results/rev.fa', "r")`

It says that no such file exists.  I have checked my spelling and I am sure that the file does exist.  I also get that file does not exist if I try to call its name as a raw string:

`input_handle = open(r'~/Documents/Research/Scala/hiv-biojava-scala/results/rev.fa', "r")`

Or if I try to call it as the following it says that no global results exists:

`input_handle = open(os.path.join(os.curdir,results/f), "r")`

Here is the full code.  If anybody knows what the problem is I would really appreciate any help that you could offer.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import os.path
import sys
import re
from Bio import SeqIO

def processFiles(files) :
    for f in files:
             process(f)

def process(f):
    input_handle = open(f, "r") 
    records = list(SeqIO.parse(input_handle, "fasta"))
    print records 
    i = 0
    while i < len(records)-1:
            temp = records[i]
            next = records[i+1]
            if (next.id == temp.id) :
                    print "duplicate found at " + next.id
                    if (len(next.seq) < len(temp.seq)) :
                            records.pop(i+1)
                    else :
                            records.pop(i)
            i = i + 1


    output_handle = open("out.fa", "w")
    for record in records:
            SeqIO.write(records, output_handle, "fasta")

    input_handle.close()



def main():
    input_folder = sys.argv[1]
    out_folder = sys.argv[2]
    if os.path.exists(out_folder):
            print("Folder %s exists; please specify empty folder or new one" %          out_folder)
            sys.exit(1)
    os.makedirs(out_folder)
    files = os.listdir(input_folder)
    print files
    processFiles(files)     



main()
```

Comment: `~` is not an actual directory.  It's a wildcard that is expanded to your home directory whenever the *shell* (not Python, and not Python's `open`) encounters it.  Either write out your home directory in full or pass the path through `os.path.expanduser` or the like before passing it to `open`.

Comment: @jwodder: Or you could just use os.environ['HOME'] to get the home directory.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos, even easier is `os.path.expanduser("~/foo/bar")`

Comment: @David: Yeah, I didn't really know that. I've never heard of os.path.expanduser. It's good to know that. I didn't know that ~ is expanded to the home directory, either. You certainly know your Python!

Comment: Thank you for the help! I was able to get it to work by passing both the folder name results and file name to the process function, and then joining those to the correct path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `input_handle = open(os.path.join(os.getcwd,results/f), "r")`. `os.curdir` returns `.` See mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2012-September/631864.html.